# Angular: add an object to an other in the same form

Tags: angular

I have trouble to link an angular object to an other.

I have an object Company which have a property accounts which is an array of FiAccounts.

```
export class Company {

  id : number;
  name : String;
  country : String;
   accounts : FiAccount[];
}

export class FiAccount {
  id:number;
  year : number;
  equity : number;
  long_term_debt : number;
  assets : number;
}
```

In my form, I create a newco and a newfi, which works fine. However, I can't bind the newfi in my newco. When I try to use:

```
this.newco.accounts.push(this.newfi);
```

I have the error in the console:

> "ERROR TypeError: this.newco.accounts is undefined"

Here is the code of my TS file. Could you explain me where I made the mistake?

```
export class NewcoComponent implements OnInit {

  newco : Company = new Company();
  newfi : FiAccount = new FiAccount();

  constructor(private service : CompanyService, private accountService : AccountsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.service.postCompany(this.newco).subscribe(() =>{
    });
    this.accountService.postAccount(this.newfi).subscribe(()=>{

    });
    this.newco.accounts.push(this.newfi);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new `Company`, the `accounts` member is undefined.

You need to initialize it to an empty array:

```
export class Company {
  id : number;
  name : String;
  country : String;
  accounts : FiAccount[] = [];
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-company-accounts?file=index.ts